# C Help: MSVC debugger gets an "error reading characters of string" error... but only sometimes

Tags: c, string, compiler-errors

I am making a 5 card poker game, but I keep getting an error when running the program in the debugger.

I ran this code through my debugger 8 times and of those I got an error 5 times — without changing any of the code. What could be causing it to read a string improperly only sometimes? Please help me figure it out.

Necessary code:

-Initialization

```
char *suit[4] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
char *face[13] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", 
"Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
Card p1_hand[5] = {{0,0,0}};
```

-Function call in main

```
print_hand(face, suit, p1_hand);
```

-Functions in header file // Card struct

```
typedef struct card
{
int card_number;
int face_index;
int suit_index;
} Card;

void print_hand (char *face[4], char *suit[13], Card p1_hand[5]);
```

-Function itself

```
void print_hand (char *face[], char *suit[], Card p1_hand[5])
{
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

printf("You're hand:\n");
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    j = p1_hand[i].face_index;
    k = p1_hand[i].suit_index;
    printf("%d: %5s of %-8s\n", (i+1), face[j], suit[k]);
}
}
```

I put a debugger stopping point before the first printf and sometimes I get this out of it

- `face   0x0040fb5c {0x0000000a Error reading characters of string.}`

but other times I get this... without changing the code at all

- `face   0x002afe40 {0x013a787c "Ace"}`  (which is correct)

Please help me figure this out! It's driving me crazy.

**EDIT**
**MY CODE**

**main.c**

```
#include "poker.h"

int main (void)
{
//initialize arrays
char *suit[4] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
char *face[13] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", 
"Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
int deck[4][13] = {0};
int num_face_player_1[13] = {0}, num_face_dealer[13] = {0};
int num_suit_player_1[4] = {0}, num_suit_dealer[4] = {0};

//Players' hands
Card p1_hand[5] = {{0,0,0}}, dealer_hand[5] = {{0,0,0}};

//Other
int count = 0;
int menu = 0, choice_menu = 0;
int invalid = 0;

srand ((unsigned) time (NULL));

//MENU
do //menu loop
{
    menu = print_menu ();
    choice_menu = 4; //so its not 0;
    choice_menu = menu_choice (menu);
} while (choice_menu ==0);
if (choice_menu == 2) //closes the game
{
    return 0;
}

system ("cls");
shuffle (deck);
deal (deck, p1_hand);

do //checks to make sure the dealer doesnt have any of the same cards
{
    deal (deck, dealer_hand);
    invalid = 0;
    for(count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        if ((dealer_hand[count].card_number == p1_hand[count].card_number) && (dealer_hand[count].face_index == p1_hand[count].face_index) && (dealer_hand[count].suit_index == p1_hand[count].suit_index))
        {
            invalid = 1;
        }
    }
} while (invalid == 1);

for(count = 0; count < 4; count++)
{
    printf("%s\n", *suit[count]);
}
for(count = 0; count < 13; count++)
{
    printf("%s\n", *face[count]);
}
print_hand(face, suit, p1_hand);

//these populate the number of facecards / suits arrays in order to see what hand you got
pop_num_faces(num_face_player_1, p1_hand);
pop_num_faces(num_face_dealer, dealer_hand);
pop_num_suit(num_suit_player_1, p1_hand);
pop_num_suit(num_suit_dealer, dealer_hand);

return 0;
}
```

**poker.h**

```
#ifndef POKER_H
#define POKER_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>

typedef struct card
{
    int card_number;
    int face_index;
    int suit_index;
} Card;

int print_menu (void);
int menu_choice (int menu_choice);
void press_any_key (void);
void shuffle (int wDeck[4][13]);
void deal(const int wDeck[][13], Card p_hand[5]);
void pop_num_faces (int num_faces[], Card hand[5]);
void pop_num_suit (int num_suit[4], Card hand[5]);
void print_hand (char *face[4], char *suit[13], Card p1_hand[5]);
void check_hand(Card p1_hand[5], int num_suit[], int num_faces[]);

#endif
```

**poker.c**

```
#include "poker.h"

//prints menu
int print_menu (void)


//decides what to do with the menu choice
int menu_choice (int menu_choice)
//Shuffles the deck
void shuffle (int wDeck[4][13])
{
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
int card = 0;

for (card = 1; card <= 52; card++)
{
    do
    {
        row = rand () % 4;
        column = rand () % 13;
    } while (wDeck[row][column] != 0);

    wDeck[row][column] = card;
}
}

//deals the deck to the player
void deal(const int wDeck[][13], Card p_hand[5])
{
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
int card = 0;
int index = 0;

for(card = 1; card < 52; card++)
{
    for (row = 0; row <4; row++)
    {
        for (column = 0; column < 13; column++)
        {
            if(wDeck[row][column] == card)
            {
                p_hand[index].card_number = card;
                p_hand[index].face_index = column;
                p_hand[index].suit_index = row;
            }
        }   
    }
    index++;
}
}

//populates num faces
void pop_num_faces (int num_faces[], Card hand[5])
{
int i = 0;

//program keeps populating num_faces with random numbers, so i have to  re-initialize here
    num_faces[0] = 0;
    num_faces[1] = 0;
    num_faces[2] = 0;
    num_faces[3] = 0;
    num_faces[4] = 0;
    num_faces[5] = 0;
    num_faces[6] = 0;
    num_faces[7] = 0;
    num_faces[8] = 0;
    num_faces[9] = 0;
    num_faces[10] = 0;
    num_faces[11] = 0;
    num_faces[12] = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    switch(hand[i].face_index)
    {
    case 0: num_faces[0] ++;
        break;
    case 1: num_faces[1] ++;
        break;
    case 2: num_faces[2] ++;
        break;
    case 3: num_faces[3] ++;
        break;
    case 4: num_faces[4] ++;
        break;
    case 5: num_faces[5] ++;
        break;
    case 6: num_faces[6] ++;
        break;
    case 7: num_faces[7] ++;
        break;
    case 8: num_faces[8] ++;
        break;
    case 9: num_faces[9] ++;
        break;
    case 10: num_faces[10] ++;
        break;
    case 11: num_faces[11] ++;
        break;
    case 12: num_faces[12] ++;
        break;
    }
}
}

//populates num_suit
void pop_num_suit (int num_suit[4], Card hand[5])
{
int i = 0;
num_suit[0] = 0;
num_suit[1] = 0;
num_suit[2] = 0;
num_suit[3] = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    switch(hand[i].suit_index)
    {
    case 0: num_suit[0] ++;
        break;
    case 1: num_suit[1] ++;
        break;
    case 2: num_suit[2] ++;
        break;
    case 3: num_suit[3] ++;
        break;
    }
}
}

void print_hand (char *face[4], char *suit[13], Card p1_hand[5])
{
printf("You're hand:\n");
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    j = p1_hand[i].face_index;
    k = p1_hand[i].suit_index;
    printf("--DEBUG--: %d %d %d\n", p1_hand[i].card_number, j, k);
    printf("%d: %5s of %-8s\n", (i+1), face[j], suit[k]);
}
}
```

Comment: I also forgot to mention that changing them to const char* doesnt help the matter

Comment: where is the Card definition?

Comment: The function looks OK - you probably need to show us the calling code and data allocations too.

Comment: What are the values of j and k when you get a crash ?

Comment: @PaulR j and k are both equal to 0.

Comment: You've not shown how the `p1_hand` array passed to the code is initialized.  The problem is likely uninitialized variables in some shape or form.

Comment: I believe a hand with 5 Aces of Hearts is unpopular with the other players in a Poker game.

Comment: @Jonathan I threw the p1_hand array initialization up there

Comment: @Aswin the Card definition is up there now

Comment: As said the initialization is the problem here.. initialise the `p_hand` based on your conditions

Comment: @Jonathan lol ya but the plan is for that to not be the case. How this function should work is the j and k become the numbers of the face and suit index in the hand (populated by a deal function), and those numbers correspond with a face and suit in the face and suit arrays, thus printing out the face and suit for that specific card. The for loop should do it for each card in the hand

Comment: The error is occurring during execution not, as you imply, at compile time.

Comment: @Keith yes it does compile correctly so you are right. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `deal()` function.  Here's a debugging version of it:

```
void deal(int wDeck[][13], Card p_hand[5])
{
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    int card = 0;
    int index = 0;

    for (card = 1; card < 52; card++)
    {
        for (row = 0; row < 4; row++)
        {
            for (column = 0; column < 13; column++)
            {
                if (wDeck[row][column] == card)
                {
                    p_hand[index].card_number = card;
                    p_hand[index].face_index = column;
                    p_hand[index].suit_index = row;
                    printf("Assign %d\n", index);
                }
            }
        }
        index++;
        printf("Index: %d\n", index);
    }
}
```

When run, `index` goes from 1 to 52; pity the `p_hand` array only has 5 elements!  And the `Assign` gets printed numerous times.  You've got array indexes horribly out of control.

---

Incidentally, you're too fond of switches.  This:

```
void pop_num_suit (int num_suit[4], Card hand[5])
{
    int i = 0;
    num_suit[0] = 0;
    num_suit[1] = 0;
    num_suit[2] = 0;
    num_suit[3] = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        switch(hand[i].suit_index)
        {
        case 0: num_suit[0] ++;
            break;
        case 1: num_suit[1] ++;
            break;
        case 2: num_suit[2] ++;
            break;
        case 3: num_suit[3] ++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
void pop_num_suit(int num_suit[4], Card hand[5])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        num_suit[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        num_suit[hand[i].suit_index]++;
}
```

The space saving in `pop_num_faces()` is even more dramatic.

Comment: The reason you see slightly different behaviour each time is that you're using `srand()`, which is good — except when you need stability.  For testing while crashing, comment out the `srand()` so that you get the same behaviour each time you run the program.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit big for a comment, hence a CW answer.

```
void print_hand(char *face[], char *suit[], Card p1_hand[5])
{
    printf("Your hand:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int j = p1_hand[i].face_index;
        int k = p1_hand[i].suit_index;
        printf("--DEBUG--: %d %d %d\n", p1_hand[i].card_number, j, k);
        printf("%d: %5s of %-8s\n", (i+1), face[j], suit[k]);
    }
}
```

This prints the data from each entry of `p1_hand` before trying to use that data.  This may tell you something about what's going on.  You could add assertions as an alternative, or addition:

```
        assert(j >= 0 && j < 13);
        assert(k >= 0 && j < 4);
```

---

#### SSCCE Code

This is more nearly an SSCCE — just over 100 lines of code that crash on Unix in the same general way it was crashing on Windows, in the `print_hand()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct card
{
    int card_number;
    int face_index;
    int suit_index;
} Card;

void shuffle(int wDeck[4][13]);
void deal(int wDeck[][13], Card p_hand[5]);
void print_hand(char *face[4], char *suit[13], Card p1_hand[5]);

static void print_deck(int deck[4][13]);

int main (void)
{
    char *suit[4] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
    char *face[13] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
        "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    int deck[4][13] = { { 0 } };
    Card p1_hand[5] = {{0,0,0}};

    srand ((unsigned) time (NULL));

    printf("Shuffle\n");
    shuffle(deck);
    print_deck(deck);

    printf("Deal player\n");
    deal(deck, p1_hand);

    printf("Print player's hand\n");
    print_hand(face, suit, p1_hand);

    return 0;
}

static void print_deck(int deck[4][13])
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < 13; z++)
            printf(" %2d", deck[x][z]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

void shuffle(int wDeck[4][13])
{
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    int card = 0;

    for (card = 1; card <= 52; card++)
    {
        do
        {
            row = rand () % 4;
            column = rand () % 13;
        } while (wDeck[row][column] != 0);

        wDeck[row][column] = card;
    }
}

void deal(int wDeck[][13], Card p_hand[5])
{
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    int card = 0;
    int index = 0;

    for (card = 1; card < 52; card++)
    {
        for (row = 0; row <4; row++)
        {
            for (column = 0; column < 13; column++)
            {
                if (wDeck[row][column] == card)
                {
                    p_hand[index].card_number = card;
                    p_hand[index].face_index = column;
                    p_hand[index].suit_index = row;
                }
            }
        }
        index++;
    }
}

void print_hand(char *face[4], char *suit[13], Card p1_hand[5])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    printf("Your hand:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        j = p1_hand[i].face_index;
        k = p1_hand[i].suit_index;
        printf("--DEBUG--: %d %d %d\n", p1_hand[i].card_number, j, k);
        printf("%d: %5s of %-8s\n", (i+1), face[j], suit[k]);
    }
}
```

The good news is that the `shuffle()` function appears to be OK.

Comment: I dont think the problem is with p1_hand... When i debug its the face[4] and suit[13] arrays that just happen to have read errors every once and awhile. p1_hand is not using any data from these arrays, and the read error occurs before any of the data is even used. (Errors occur before the first printf when debugging)

Comment: So the problem is almost certainly not in the `print_hand()` function.  Maybe you should print the addresses of the arrays on entry to the function; they should be the same every time.  But if you've got problems in the code that's calling `print_hand()`, then you need to show that.  At the moment, I think it is more likely in the calling code (or other code called by the calling code) than in the code you've shown.  You are compiling with maximum compiler warnings enabled and the code has no warnings, aren't you?

Comment: It probably means you have pointers out of control.  You've likely trampled on your `face` and `suit` arrays with non-pointer data.  Since you haven't shown the `main()` function, there's nothing much we can do.  Since you're using MSVS, you can't easily get `valgrind` onto the job; it can often help.  My guess is you've got something like: `char *buffer; fgets(buffer, 200, stdin);` in your code, and the data is being read into random memory.  It may not be quite that blatant, but...well, that's a guess based on very limited data.  If you won't show your code, you won't get the help.

Comment: And thanks alot for helping me work through this

Comment: Imgur is not offering me a chance to download a readable image this time.  Can't you copy and paste the code into your question?  We don't want print screens; we just need the C code (plain text, indented sanely).  Maybe you need to learn about how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Reducing your problem to a minimal reproduction often points out the error of your ways.  (You are using a VCS — version control system — so you can make changes to your code and get back to where you were confidently, aren't you?)

Comment: Reduce the code to the bare minimum that reproduces the problem.  It should be small enough to fit in the question — if it isn't, you probably haven't done a good enough job of minimization.  Also, the first Win API function or header means I'm off the job — I don't do Windows.

Comment: I believe the problem is the deal function, but I cannot see how or why it would be interfering.

Comment: Yes but if I debug your code in Windows, placing a breakpoint in main before the print hand function but after the deal function, the values in the face and suit array have read errors already. So the problem occurs before the print function, even though the print function is where the program will crash.

Comment: Yes: see my other answer.  The problem is that the `deal()` function is overwriting random memory beyond the end of the player's hand (`p1_hand` in `main()`), and that is corrupting the `deck` and then the `face` and `suit` arrays, and hence you get garbage printed.  You get random variations because you use `srand()`; when debugging a problem, disable (comment out) `srand()` so you get the same sequence of random numbers each time.  You want `srand()` in production; you don't when debugging.

Comment: I didn't even see your second answer, just the addition to the first one. But yes that seems to be the problem here. And it looks like a small change fixed my code! Oh my goodness thank you so much for your patience and help. This problem would have driven me mad all night.